# Comparing two dates within same month in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a scenario where I would like to determine if a certain payment has been paid before a certain due date. The due date variable is just an integer from `1-30`. Now this payment is supposed to be paid on a monthly basis so if the due date is `6th` then every month on `6th` I'm expecting the payment to be done. What I currently have is the following

```
DateTime.strptime(@payment.created.to_s,'%s') <= Date.new(Date.today.year, Date.today.month, @offer.due_date)
```

the `offer` model holds the due date and the payment comes in as a linux timestamp that's why the conversion. Now the problem with this simple logic is that it doesn' take into account the month at all. So `DateTime.strptime(@payment.created.to_s,'%s')` could be the payment for the last month and this would evaluate to true which would be not okay. How can I consider this logic, but on a monthly basis?

Comment: Why is your `created` field not a proper `DateTime` field? Requiring parsing is making a huge mess of things here. If, for whatever reason, that's a timestamp then `Time.at(@payment.created)` should convert it.

Comment: It seems that you might need to consider the number of payments made, too. For instance, if I start this subscription in Jan and have to pay before the 6th of each month, what if I pay three payments on Jan 5? The Jan 6 deadline would have to return true, Feb true, March true, but April false. Seems like you might need a method that compares the number of payments made before the due date. I'd also use Rails's timestamps here and just use `created_at`.

Comment: @tadman It's coming from Stripe which returns a unix timestamp instead of DateTime field.

Comment: @Reba The issue is that simply from a "created" timestamp, no matter which style, one cannot decide whether the payment in question is on due. With recurring due dates and payments, many "race conditions" can happen: multiple advance payments, single ommitted payments with later ones on due etc. You cannot put all that domain logic into one boolean expression. I would create a RecurrentPayment model with one instance per due date. The instances hold absolute payment dates and their payment status. A new payment would then be iterated against all open payments until a match is found.

Comment: You should convert it, then save it as a proper DateTime. Keeping them raw is problematic. If necessary keep the raw value in a column, but use the converted one for calculations like this.